# python process failed to load environment variables in OSX

Tags: python, terminal-emacs

In Emacs 25 GUI, 
1. Shell process loads environment variables,
2. Python process, started by *run-python*, doesn't load environment variables.

Run Emacs terminal mode in iTem2: Both shell and python process load environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

Under OSX, Emacs itself wont, by default, load the same environment as your user unless you either:

1. Start emacs from the shell (in terminal or gui mode)
2. Use the `exec-path-from-shell` package, [here](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)
3. Manually assemble Emacs' path from your users' PATH in your init.el (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

If all you're interested in, are the `PATH` and `MANPATH` variables, one way to get good values for those, are with this code (snipped from my emacs init file):

```
(let ((path-helper
   (lambda (p pd)
     (with-temp-buffer
       (mapc (lambda (filename)
           (insert-file-contents filename)
           (goto-char (point-max))
           (unless (bolp) (insert "\n")))
         (cons p (directory-files pd t "[^.]")))
       (let (res)
     (goto-char (point-min))
     (while (< (point) (point-max))
       (setq res (cons (buffer-substring
                (point) (progn (end-of-line) (point)))
               res))
       (forward-char 1))
     (nreverse res))))))
  (setq exec-path (funcall path-helper "/etc/paths" "/etc/paths.d"))
  (setenv "PATH" (mapconcat #'identity exec-path ":"))
  (setenv "MANPATH"
      (mapconcat #'identity
         (funcall path-helper "/etc/manpaths" "/etc/manpaths.d")
         ":")))
```

But then, of course, you need to maintain the files `/etc/paths`, `/etc/paths.d/*`,  `/etc/manpaths`, and `/etc/manpaths.d/*`. In any case, in the default setup, your login shell on OS X uses those files to set these variables, with the help of the `path_helper` utility, so this should be no great burden.